# Aligning form input boxes?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, alignment

I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3zSbt/

I don't know how I'd even up my input boxes with eachother...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div id="contactContent">
 <form>
 Email: <input type="text" name="firstName">
 <br>
 Subject: <input type="text" name="lastName">
 </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contactContent { margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 300px;}
input { border: none; margin-left: 50px; margin-bottom: 30px; padding-right: 50px;}
```

Comment: There are many ways. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3zSbt/1/).

Comment: Anyway works for me as long as it looks like your example. You should make it an answer so I can check it off. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many ways. One way is putting your *value names* in `label`. Example:

**HTML**

```
<label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="firstName" />
<br />
<label>Subject:</label><input type="text" name="lastName" />
```

**CSS**

```
label{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zSbt/1/).

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use HTML you could try putting it in a table, or if you just want to use CSS have you tried this;

```
input {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Was trying to avoid the use of a table.

Comment: Fair enough, but hope the CSS is a solution for you.